# Spark Session - behaviour on configs during reuse

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When I execute the code in Spark Shell or Jupyter Notebook, I often encounter the following warning message: "WARN SparkSession: Using an existing Spark session; only runtime SQL configurations will have an impact."

As per the spark doc (https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate.html), it was mentioned that "In case an existing SparkSession is returned, the config options specified in this builder will be applied to the existing SparkSession".

Does this mean, shuffle for application-1 gets updated from 20 to 30 in below case if application-2 reuses spark session from application-1? Is not this counter intuitive behaviour where one application overwriting another application config?

Run application-1:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a SparkSession-1 and run
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("my-application-1").config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",20).getOrCreate()
```

Run application-2: created while application-1 is till running

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("my-application-2").config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",30).getOrCreate()
```

**Update**:
I ran below code first and got see  ('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions', '20') in output of getAll()

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a SparkSession-1 and run
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("my-application-1").config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",20).getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()
```

Later I ran below, where this reused previous session. ie got an message "Using an existing Spark session; only runtime SQL configurations will take effect". But getAll() returned this  ('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions', '20')

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("my-application-2").config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",30).getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()
```

Comment: you could test this in your environment by running the [`getAll`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkConf.getAll.html#pyspark-sparkconf-getall) method after each statement.

Comment: I reran the code using getAll(), posted the details at the end of question above. When application-2 reused session-1 created by application-1, it still continues to use partitions of 20 instead of 30. But as mentioned in the spark doc ie. "In case an existing SparkSession is returned, the config options specified in this builder will be applied to the existing SparkSession", should not it use 30?. Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the idea of sharing Spark Sessions is exactly that. But it is poorly explained. As zero323, the ex-contributor to SO, and MR Powers also state.

- Spark session sharing (via spark-shell, not spark-submit) is for sharing Spark Views on things like Databricks and note book environments that support that - not all do. Other people can access you various views.
- Reuse of a Spark session means that you inherit the same settings, whatever you specify yourself, as you have observed.
- Of course you can alter the shuffle partitions value inline in you shell, notebook.

From https://mrpowers.medium.com/great-questions-175d0a6c749a :

> Great questions!
>
> When you start the Spark shell, a SparkSession is created and is
> accessible via the spark variable.
>
> When you run sbt console a SparkSession is not created, so you need to
> create your own with val spark =
> SparkSession.builder().master(“local”).appName(“my-app”).getOrCreate()
>
> The WARN SparkSession$Builder: Using an existing SparkSession; some
> configuration may not take effect. warning message is a bit confusing
> because it makes it seem like something is wrong, when everything is
> working fine. The getOrCreate() method let’s us reuse an existing
> SparkSession. It gives this warning when you use an existing
> SparkSession to let you know that an existing SparkSession is being
> used, even if you tried to change the configuration (we aren’t
> changing the configuration and we want to reuse the existing
> SparkSession, so this warning message can be ignored).

You can of course wants

Comment: thank you. regarding the point "Of course you can alter the shuffle partitions value inline in you shell, notebook.", here I have tried to alter using config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions",30), but it inherited from existing session ie value 20. So is it fair to conclude it inherits all settings from existing session during reuse of session and we cannot change config values?

Comment: Some things can be changed some not. Shuffle partitions can be changed, but nit a hive metastore you could point to for a given session.

Comment: got it. If "Shuffle partitions can be changed", trying to understand why was it not changed in above examples?